# How to calculate $(n^{-1})\%(p^a)$ for prime $p$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I actually needed to calculate $(a/b)\%m$ when $m$ is not prime. Here is what I have done so far.

$(a/b)\%m = (a* \text{modinv}(b))\%m$, I can calculate mod inverse only if $m$ and $b$ are co-primes.

So, $m= p_1^{k_1}  p_2^{k_2} \cdots p_n^{k_n}$.

For each prime factor, I will separately calculate $(a/b)\%(p_i^{k_i})$ and then combine all the answers using Chinese Remainder Theorem.

The problem is I am unable to calculate $(a/b)\%(p^k)$, can I please get some help on this.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please learn how to format math for this site (simple things like those in your question are not hard to do). See [formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) . You may also find the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) useful.

Comment: You can be more direct and use [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem). Or, if you like being optimal, [Carmichael's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function).

Comment: There are much more computationally efficient ways, such as the Extended Euclidean Algorithm. No factorization, no CRT.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Can you please elaborate ? I though Extended Euclidean Algorithm will work only if $b$ and $m$ are co-prime.

Comment: If $b$ and $m$ are not relatively prime, then $b$ does not have an inverse modulo $m$. However, if you want to solve $bx\equiv a\pmod{m}$, you can compute the gcd $d$ of $b$ and $m$. If $d$ does not divide $a$, there is no solution. If $d$ divides $a$, use the Euclidean Algorithm so solve $(b/d)x\equiv a/d\pmod{m/d}$. There will be a unique solution modulo $m/d$, but several modulo $m$.

Comment: Do you mean $\pmod x$ when you use $\%x$ as we do in Python?

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you are trying to solve the congruence $bx\equiv a\pmod{m}$.

If $b$ and $m$ are coprime, use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm to find a $z$ such that $bz\equiv 1\pmod{m}$. Then $az$ is a solution of $bx\equiv a\pmod{m}$, and it is unique modulo $m$.

If $b$ and $m$ are not coprime, then $b$ does not have a modular inverse modulo $m$. However, sometimes we can solve the congruence $bx\equiv a\pmod{m}$.

Let $d=\gcd(b,m)$. If $d$ does not divide $a$, then our congruence does not have a solution.  So suppose that $d$ divides $a$.

Then $b/d$ and $m/d$ are relatively prime. The congruence $(b/d)y\equiv a/d\pmod{(m/d)}$ has a unique solution modulo $m/d$, which we can obtain using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm.

However, the congruence has $d$ solutions modulo $m$, and from each of these solutions we can obtain a solution of $bx\equiv a\pmod{m}$.

Informally, if $b$ and $m$ are not relatively prime, then $a/b$ need not exist modulo $m$, and when it exists it is not uniquely defined modulo $m$.